# Removing elements of string before a specific repeated character in it in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split, substring, trim

I'm trying to remove  from my string all elements before an specific character which is repeated several times in this way:

```
let string = http://localhost:5000/contact-support
```

thus I´m just trying to remove everything before the third `/`
having as result:`contact_support`

for that i just set:

```
string.substring(string.indexOf('/') + 3);
```

Bust guess thats not the correct way

Any help about how to improve this in the simplest way please?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to do some URL parsing here. JS brings the handful `URL` utility which can help you with this, and other similar tasks.

```js
const myString = 'http://localhost:5000/contact-support';

const pathname = new URL(myString).pathname;

console.log(pathname); // outputs: /contact-support

// then you can also remove the first "/" character with `substring`
const whatIActuallyNeed = pathname.substring(1, pathname.length);

console.log(whatIActuallyNeed); // outputs: contact-support
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope This will work**

```
string.split("/")[3]
```

It will return the sub-string after the 3rd forward slash.

Comment: super simple and super effective. Thanks@ Abir

Comment: You are welcome..!! Hope you will select my answer..!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `lastIndexOf('/')`, like this:

```
string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Another possibility is regular expressions:

```
string.match(/[^\/]*\/\/[^\/]*\/(.*)/)[1];
```

Note that you must escape the slash, since it is the delimiter in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

`string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('/')+1)` will also do the job if you are looking to use indexOf function explicitly.